# Consultar datos en una tabla de una base de datos de un servicio host mediante Retrofit (Android)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-asynctask

Estoy buscando la manera de consultar datos en una tabla de una BBDD alojada en un servicio host mediante retrofit desde android Studio.

---

El problema es que para entrar y ver los datos directamente con phpMyAdmin desde el servicio host necesito:

  1. Poner mi usuario y pass para el servicio de host.

  2. Seleccionar una BBDD.

  3. Poner mi usuario y pass para phpMyAdmin.

  4. Y seleccionar la tabla de la base de datos.

Sé que una vez instanciado el objeto de la clase Retrofit, tengo que darle una URL básica. Porque imagino que debería de poner alguna credencial más, pero no encuentro un ejemplo de como hacerlo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Retrofit te permite conectar tu app Android con una API HTTP, pero NO directamente con una base de datos MySQL. Lo mas normal en este tipo de situaciones sería desarrollar una API REST en tu servidor, (como mencionaste que usabas PHPMyAdmin, seguramente puedas hacer una API en PHP) para que mediante llamadas HTTP (que Retrofit si puede hacer) te permita acceder a los datos alojados en tu MySQL.

Como alternativa, podrías buscar alguna librería que te permita conectar Android directamente con un servidor MySQL, pero no es una práctica muy recomendada.

**Edit:**
Estuve averiguando un poco mas, y alguien ya hizo el trabajo sucio. Podés mirar [esta](https://github.com/maantje/Jackend) librería: agregando un archivo php en tu servidor, te permite acceder directamente a los datos utilizando una estructura de datos json. Si seguís pensando en conectarte directamente a MySQL, podés sacar algunas ideas de [éste post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23973372/android-mysql-connector-java-library), donde intentan acceder directamente a MySQL desde Android usando un driver jdbc.